# flutter : hide status bar (bottom)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a design in adobe xd. I want to apply it to flutter. The application should not have a status bar bottom in all layout screens. I added this code in the main:

main code :

```dart
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
       overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

status bar bottom has actually disappeared but when I press a button to enter another screen it appears first on the first click and when I press again it moves to the other screen and remains visible and does not disappear even though I put the status bar bottom code in the main

These attached pictures illustrate my explanation above in full:
:
[image: First, as soon as the application is launched, the status bar bottom disappears]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

**Hide Statusbar**

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode([SystemUiOverlay.bottom])
```

**For Single Screen**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // put hide code here to hide statusbar
    super.initState();
  }
```